# What is this headset's name per the Standardized Headset Identification System

Tags: headset

The Park Tool website has a page describing the [standardized headset identification system](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/standardized-headset-identification-system).

I would like to confirm that I've understood it properly. Is this bottom  section of a press-fit headset shown in the picture a `ZS56/40`?

NOTE: I've taken measurements with inexpensive digital calipers and the fractional component of the value can change significantly depending on how much force is applied when turning the thumbwheel.

[image: lower press-fit headset section]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes ZS56/40 - Zero stack with 56 mm bore diameter and 40 mm fork crown race.

It is zero stack because it is a black cup containing the silver bearing, but the bearing ends up inside the frame tube (i.e. not external). The 56.10 mm dimension gives a snug interference fit with a 56 mm head tube ( bore diameter). The 39.95 or so is about the 40 mm dimension that interfaces with the crown race/steerer tube. That last measurement seems slightly tight but possibly measurement error, tolerances aside it would be called a 40 mm.